# Предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

При использовании

```
unordered_map<ident_table_key, ident_table_value> semantic::ident_table;
```

получаю ошибки:

1. Ошибка   C2280   "std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию;
2. Ошибка   C2064   результатом вычисления фрагмента не является функция, принимающая 1 аргументов.

Первая возникает в файле `unordered_map`, вторая - в `xhash`. Читал, что в подобных случаях надо реализовать конструктор копирования, но это не помогло. В чем дело?

**ident_table_key.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ident_table_key
{
public:
    string ident_name; 
    string region; 
    ident_table_key(string id_name, string reg);
    ident_table_key(const ident_table_key& key);
};
```

**ident_table_key.cpp**

```
#include "ident_table_key.h"

ident_table_key::ident_table_key(string id_name, string reg): ident_name(id_name), region(reg) {}

ident_table_key::ident_table_key(const ident_table_key& key) {
    ident_name = key.ident_name;
    region = key.region;
}
```

**ident_table_value.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "csymbol.h"

class ident_table_value
{
public:
    ident_table_value(ident_type tp);
    ident_table_value(ident_type tp, bool bv); 
    ident_type type;
    bool boolean_value;
};
```

**ident_table_value.cpp**

```
#include "ident_table_value.h"

ident_table_value::ident_table_value(ident_type tp): type(tp), boolean_value(NULL) {}

ident_table_value::ident_table_value(ident_type tp, bool bv): type(tp), boolean_value(bv) {}
```

Comment: а где реализация `std::hash` для `ident_table_key`?

Comment: или же  хэшируйте по  ident_table_key::name

Comment: @ARHovsepyan можно поподробнее? просто я не знаток плюсов

Comment: @Fat-Zer можете объяснить, как это сделать?

Comment: @ mtrfnv,  можно, но сначала расскажите что за тип ident_table_value?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan обновил текст вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы использовать контейнер [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) ключевой тип должен соответствовать нескольким условиям:

- Для него должна быть определён функциональный объект `Hash` (опциональный параметр шаблона), по умолчанию это [`std::hash<Key_T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).
- Для него должен быть определён предикат сравнения на равенство `Pred` (второй необязательный аргумент шаблона `unordered_map`), по умолчанию это [`std::equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to), который опять же по умолчанию раскрывается в `operator==`.
- Для него должен существовать конструктор копирования (конструктор копирования по умолчанию тоже подойдёт).

Реализация `operator==` достаточно тривиальна:

```
class ident_table_key {
    // ...
    bool operator== (const ident_table_key& other) const {
        return this->ident_name == other.ident_name &&
               this->region     == other.region;
    }
};
```

Для hash'а можно воспользоваться примером с *cppreference*, но ИМХО лучше его немного модифицировать и использовать вместо обычного сдвига циклический:

```
namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<ident_table_key> {   
        size_t operator() (const ident_table_key & arg) const {
            size_t h1 = hash<string>{}( arg.ident_name );
            size_t h2 = hash<string>{}( arg.region );

            return h1 ^ (h2>>1) ^ (h2 << (sizeof(size_t)*CHAR_BIT - 1));
        }
    };
}
```

Кроме того, как отмечается в коментариях на том же *cppreference* для подобных случаев неплохо было бы использовать [`boost::hash_combine()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) (но для большинства случаев и простое решение даст вполне приемлемый результат).

Answer (score 0):

Если есть затруднения в написании хэш функции для вашего класса, то можно сделать также следующее:
Допишите оператор в классе

```
class ident_table_key
{
public:
    // ...
    operator string() { return ident_name + "  " + region; }    
};
```

теперь  вашим ключом может быть  string(ident_name + region)
но только вместо  типа

```
unordered_map<ident_table_key, ident_table_value>
```

ваш обьект будет иметь тип

```
unordered_map<std::string, ident_table_value>
```

Например:

```
int main()
{    
    unordered_map<string, ident_table_value> ident_table;
    ident_table_key f1(...);
    ident_table_value  val(...)
    ident_table[f1] = val;  // ключом является f1.ident_name
    cout << ident_table[f1].type;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Каково будет поведение программы, когда в `ident_table` будут содержаться значения с ключами с одинаковыми `ident_name`, но с разными `region`? Правильно ли я понимаю, что случится коллизия? И выдаст ли запрос нужное `ident_table_value` при обращении к таким элементам?

Comment: То есть мне требуется вести поиск именно по `ident_name` и `region`. В предложенном вами варианте если я буду вести поиск `ident_table.find(ident_table_key("sym.ident", "region"))`, то учитываться будет только `"sym_ident"`. Но в моем случае в `unordered_map` могут содержаться значения, `ident_name` которых могут совпадать, поэтому мне необходимо дополнительно идентифицировать их по `region`

Comment: так возвращайте в операторе не ident_name, а  ident_name + region.  и будет вам счастье. Я же не знаю цель вашей программы, а лишь даю идею, а вы еще возмущаетесь. А если не нравится этот вариант то сами придумайте другой.  Или напишите хэш функцию для своего класса. Не все же на подносе преподнести вам.

Comment: Я вам написал в комментарий:  или же хэшируйте по ident_table_key::name, вы попросили показать как, а после как я показал, вас не устроил этот вариант.   Теперь я изменил ответ. И думаю этот ответ тоже вас не устроит,   Напишите так, как вас устраивает, и не спрашивайте, если ответ не нужен